# Old Eclipse Javadoc generator version?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, java-8, javadoc

I use a lot of Java SE 8 features in the project, IDE is Eclipse on Mac. The code works well, but it seems, that Javadoc creator don't understand these innovations:

> illegal start of expression `.map((num)->num.toString())`
>   ')' expected `.reduce((s1, s2)-> s1 + " " + s2);`
>   etc...

Is my proposition correct? If so, how can I update Javadoc version up to 8?

**Update.**

My preferences:
[image: JRE]
[image: Path]

Isn't Java 8 everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Set your eclipse JRE to JDK 8 runtime.

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE -> Edit -> Directory and selecting the JDK 8 installation folder.
```

And also make sure you are starting the eclipse with JDK 8 runtime. Check both your JAVA_HOME and PATH variables for JDK 8 compiler (or) from cmd line with `java -version`

[image]

Comment: I already use JDK 1.8. The code works fine, problem is about javadoc only.

Comment: @AivanF. Updated the answer.

Comment: Terminal tells this: `java version "1.6.0_65" // Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4828a) // Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)` So, I have runtime version 1.6 while develop with 1.8? How is it possible?..

Comment: @AivanF. It's because you have old JDK in PATH. Change your environment settings to point to JDK 8, and restart the eclipse to pick up JDK 8 javadoc.

Comment: Could you have a look on additional info in my question? What and where do I have to change?

Comment: @AivanF. It's outside of the eclipse. Updated the answer.

Comment: it seems, your last answer edit was skipped - no changes.. Also I found out that at I have `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javadoc` but do not have this program in 1.8 jdk path. That kind of nonsense?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that documentation is generated by this file: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javadoc`. However, I didn't have such file for JDK8. Thus, I downloaded last update and wrote path to the *javadoc*-file by myself while generating in Eclipse.